# How to deploy a existing SSIS Package in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deployment, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on SSIS Package .I added one more data flow task to existing ssis package.After complition of adding new task i rebuilded the Package it was suceed with out any errors .
Do i need to deploy it to Development server?

Comment: The 2012 release of SSIS has two different deployment models: the new project deployment model and the existing package deployment model. Which do you use? Stated differently, look at your project in SSDT. Do you see a `Project.params` file listed as the first thing or do you see `Data Sources`? The former is Project deployment model, latter is package deployment model.

Comment: @billinkc: SSIDB was there in my SSMS.I think it is project deployement model.So how i will deploy if it is project deployemnt model.

Comment: SSDT is Visual Studio. SSMS is *probably* your query editing tool. This is a Project Deployment Model http://i.stack.imgur.com/XOH8b.png This is the Package Deployment Model http://i.stack.imgur.com/HW0nd.png

Comment: @billinkc. I am using Project Deployement model .

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## Background

The [2012 SSIS Project Deployment model](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx) in Visual Studio contains a file for project parameters, project level connection managers, packages and anything else you've added to the project.

In the following picture, you can see that I have a Solution named Lifecycle. That solution has a project named Lifecycle. The Lifecycle project has a Project Level Connection Manager `ERIADOR` defined and two SSIS packages: Package00.dtsx and Package01.dtsx.

[image: Solution to project to file relationship]

When you run a package, behind the scenes Visual Studio will first build/compile all the required project elements into a deployable quantum called an ispac (pronounced eye-ess-pack, not ice-pack). This will be found in the `bin\Development` subfolder for your project.

[image: Lifecycle.ispac]

Lifecycle.ispac is a zip filed with the following contents.

[image: Exploded ispac]

What's all this mean? The biggest difference is that instead of just deploying an updated package, you'll need to deploy the whole .ispac. Yes, you really have to redeploy everything even though you only changed one package. Such is life.

## How do I deploy packages using the SSIS Project Deployment model?

You have a host options available to you but at the 3 things you will need to know are

- where is my ispac
- what server am I deploying to
- what folder does this project to

### SSDT

This will probably be your most common option in the beginning. Within SQL Server Data Tools, SSDT, you have the ability to define at the Configuration Manager level what server and what folder things are deployed to. At my client, I have 3 configurations: Dev, Stage, Production. Once you define those values, they get saved into the .dtproj file and you can then right click and deploy to your heart's content from visual studio.

[image]

### ISDeploymentWizard - GUI flavor

SSDT is really just building the call to the ISDeploymentWizard.exe which comes in 32 and 64 bit flavors for some reason.

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe

An .ispac extension is associated to the ISDeploymentWizard so double click and away you go. The first screen is new compared to using the SSDT interface but after that, it will be the same set of clicks to deploy.

### ISDeploymentWizard - command line flavor

What they got right with the 2012 release that sucked with the package deployment model was that the manifest file can be deployed in an automated fashion. I had a [workaround](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html) but it should have been a standard "thing".

So look carefully at the Review tab from either the SSDT or GUI deploy. Isn't that a beauty?

[image: Silent install option]

Using the same executable, ISDeploymentWizard, we can have both an attended and unattended installer for our .ispac(s). Highlight the second line there, copy paste and now you can have continuous integration!

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe 
/Silent 
/SourcePath:"C:\Dropbox\presentations\SSISDB Lifecycle\Lifecycle\Lifecycle\bin\Development\Lifecycle.ispac" 
/DestinationServer:"localhost\dev2012" 
/DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/Folder/Lifecycle"
```

### TSQL

You can deploy an ispac to SQL Server through SQL Server Management Studio, SSMS, or through the command line, sqlcmd.exe. While [SQLCMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) is not strictly required, it simplifies the script.

You **must** use a windows account to perform this operation though otherwise you'll receive the following error message.

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows Authentication.

Furthermore, you'll need the ability to perform bulk operations (to serialize the .ispac) and ssis_admin/sa rights to the SSISDB database.

Here we use the OPENROWSET with the BULK option to read the ispac into a varbinary variable. We create a folder via [catalog.create_folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877991.aspx) if it doesn't already exist and then actually deploy the project with [catalog.deploy_project](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878004.aspx). Once done, I like to check the operations messages table to verify things went as expected.

```
USE SSISDB
GO

-- You must be in SQLCMD mode
-- setvar isPacPath "C:\Dropbox\presentations\SSISDB Lifecycle\Lifecycle\Lifecycle\bin\Development\Lifecycle.ispac"
:setvar isPacPath "<isPacFilePath, nvarchar(4000), C:\Dropbox\presentations\SSISDB Lifecycle\Lifecycle\Lifecycle\bin\Development\Lifecycle.ispac>"

DECLARE
    @folder_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @folder_id bigint = NULL
,   @project_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @project_stream varbinary(max)
,   @operation_id bigint = NULL;

-- Read the zip (ispac) data in from the source file
SELECT
    @project_stream = T.stream
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'$(isPacPath)', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS B
) AS T (stream);

-- Test for catalog existences
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        CF.name
    FROM
        catalog.folders AS CF
    WHERE
        CF.name = @folder_name
)
BEGIN
    -- Create the folder for our project
    EXECUTE [catalog].[create_folder] 
        @folder_name
    ,   @folder_id OUTPUT;
END

-- Actually deploy the project
EXECUTE [catalog].[deploy_project] 
    @folder_name
,   @project_name
,   @project_stream
,   @operation_id OUTPUT;

-- Check to see if something went awry
SELECT
    OM.* 
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    OM.operation_message_id = @operation_id;
```

### Your MOM

As in, your [Managed Object Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/26/overview-of-the-ssis-mom.aspx) provides a .NET interface for deploying packages. This is a PowerShell approach for deploying an ispac along with creating the folder as that is an option the ISDeploymentWizard does not support.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null

#this allows the debug messages to be shown
$DebugPreference = "Continue"

# Retrieves a 2012 Integration Services CatalogFolder object
# Creates one if not found
Function Get-CatalogFolder
{
    param
    (
        [string] $folderName
    ,   [string] $folderDescription
    ,   [string] $serverName = "localhost\dev2012"
    )

    $connectionString = [String]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", $serverName)

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

    $integrationServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices($connection)
    # The one, the only SSISDB catalog
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

    $catalogFolder = $catalog.Folders[$folderName]

    if (-not $catalogFolder)
    {
        Write-Debug([System.string]::Format("Creating folder {0}", $folderName))
        $catalogFolder = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder($catalog, $folderName, $folderDescription)
        $catalogFolder.Create()
    }

    return $catalogFolder
}

# Deploy an ispac file into the SSISDB catalog
Function Deploy-Project
{
    param
    (
        [string] $projectPath
    ,   [string] $projectName
    ,   $catalogFolder
    )

    # test to ensure file exists
    if (-not $projectPath -or  -not (Test-Path $projectPath))
    {
        Write-Debug("File not found $projectPath")
        return
    }

    Write-Debug($catalogFolder.Name)
    Write-Debug("Deploying $projectPath")

    # read the data into a byte array
    [byte[]] $projectStream = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($projectPath)

    # $ProjectName MUST match the value in the .ispac file
    # else you will see 
    # Failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again later.:The specified project name, test, does not match the project name in the deployment file.
    $projectName = "Lifecycle"

    $project = $catalogFolder.DeployProject($projectName, $projectStream)
}




$isPac = "C:\Dropbox\presentations\SSISDB Lifecycle\Lifecycle\Lifecycle\bin\Development\Lifecycle.ispac"
$folderName = "Folder"
$folderName = "SSIS2012"
$folderDescription = "I am a description"
$serverName = "localhost\dev2012"

$catalogFolder = Get-CatalogFolder $folderName $folderDescription $serverName

Deploy-Project $isPac $projectName $catalogFolder
```

Comment: Excellent answer, Bill.  One other thing - be sure that the Integration Services are installed on the server to which you are deploying.  It will act as if you can create an integration services catalog, but give you an error that it cannot locate the database, if they aren't.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks especially for pointing out the command line expression in the deployment wizard GUI.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried the tsql approach, using SQL auth and ran into the same roadblocks:  `The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows Authentication. `

Comment: @PhilG I updated the answer to include the need for a windows account.

Comment: Managed Object Model approach also requires an account that uses Windows Authentication.

Comment: Excellent answer. Realising that there is both a 32 and 64 bit version of ISDeploymentWizard.exe helped me understand why our automated deployment (using the 64 bit version) would convert some 3rd party tasks to "SSIS.ReplacementTask", causing the package to fail validation. This was because we only had 32 bit versions of the 3rd party assemblies available for this specific task. Switch to the 32 bit version of ISDeploymentWizard solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an update on deploying a single package in SSIS 2016 (hope this can be useful).

With the release of SQL Server 2016 and SSDT 2015 the issue of single package deployment is now a thing of the past. There is the new **Deploy Package** option (VS 2015) that comes up for deploying individual packages within a project deployment model

[image: Deploy Package option in VS 2015]

With this new feature, you can also deploy multiple packages, by clicking and holding down the control key (Ctrl) and then choosing the packages you want to deploy.

Besides the Deploy Package option in Visual Studio 2015, there are some other possibilities you may use to deploy packages, like launching **ISDeploymentWizard** application or doing **Command Line Deployment** (this one is necessary when SSIS build and deployment is automated or managed as part of Continuous Integration process). You can learn more by navigating to this article: http://www.sqlshack.com/single-package-deployment-in-sql-server-integration-services-2016/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Project Model in SSIS 2012, you have to deploy the project every time you make any change in package.
You can simply do is :

- RIGHT Click on Project and Deploy