# SSIS Project Deployment server name and project path missing on .ispac double-click

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Recently we had some problems with a production deployment of our SSIS project through an .ispac where the team performing the installation deployed to the wrong project folder and messed up our production environment :)

Our environment: SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, SSDT 2012

The installation process was a double-click on the .ispac through to the deployment wizard. The problem was clearly on the "Select Destination" page, where the "Server Name" and "Path" fields aren't automatically filled and so they had to browse to the project folder in SSISDB and got it wrong (there is another project with a similar name). I would like to get the wizard to recognize the server and path configured in the configuration settings of the SSDT project, but so far I haven't got any luck.

We have 5 different environments, each with different values for "Server Name" and "Server Project Path" on the project property page (Configuration Properties > Deployment > Deployment Model (Project)). In theory this would be enough for the wizard to recognize the settings right?

Also, if I deploy the project to the development server directly from VS2012 I get the destination fields correctly filled, but we can't use this method for a production deployment unfortunately.

Is there any way to force the SSIS deployment wizard to recognize the deployment settings when double-clicking the .ispac?

Comment: You can use Command line in a batch file for production deployment. Refer to link [SSIS Deployment](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/ssis-deployment-sql-server-2012). Scroll to `Deploying from the command line`

Comment: Also of interest, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555086/how-to-deploy-a-existing-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012/21558737#21558737

Comment: I'd prefer using solely the .ispac, but I think I'll try and get a batch to launch ISDeploymentWizard as suggested, I tried it in the dev environment and it worked well. My goal is to make it the less interactive and error-prone possible.  
Shouldn't the .ispac get loaded with the VS project configurations regarding the deployment location? I don't see much of a security risk and it would be more user friendly..  
Thank you for your help @t_m and @billinkc!

Comment: Nope, the ispac is the output of the project. Once you have that, there's no link back to your Visual Studio project (and settings). I completely understand the desire to remove opportunities for bad deployments, lost a bit of hair to issue myself.