# Migrate SSIS package from Visual Studio 2013 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I have deployed a SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2013 to SQL Server 2014 SSIS catalog. But I can not run the package. Here is the error massage:

> Package1:Error: Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 incompatibility with MS SQL Server 2014](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351741/visual-studio-2013-incompatibility-with-ms-sql-server-2014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the .dtsx file for the following entry:-

```
<DTS:Property
    DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
```

a value of 8 would indicate the package is written for sql 2014; a value of 6 indicates sql 2012.

The error message indicates that you are attempting to run a package written for sql2014 in a 2012 environment, which doesn't fit with what you are doing.

If the version is 8 and your sql is 2014, then you could try updating to SSDT 2015, and re-executing the package from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything that might be relevant is described at [SSIS package upgraded by deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091264/ssis-package-upgraded-by-deployment).

Basically even if your Visual Studio SSDT-BI and the server match perfectly, you still have to use the right ISDeploymentWizard.exe.